# Mac Cocoa How to scroll another App that under a view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, scroll, screenshot, capture

I'm trying to make a screenshot capture App. The App will first place a semitransparent full screen dark view over other Apps, this will make other Apps not responding to mouse scrolling event. How can I set a view covers other Apps and keep them respond to scrolling event? Thanks.

1. Ignore MyApp's dark view?

or

2. Send event to other Apps in MyApp?

> ```
>  -(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
>     NSLog(@"user scrolled %f horizontally and %f vertically", [theEvent deltaX], [theEvent deltaY]);
> }
> ```

### Edited:

Found a way to get a App's pid and Followed @Willeke's reference, write the following code, but not work.

```
-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super scrollWheel:theEvent];

    CGEventRef wheelevent = CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent(NULL, kCGScrollEventUnitLine, 1, theEvent.deltaY, theEvent.deltaX);

    // AppPid is gotten before mouse wheel scrolls
    CGEventPostToPid(AppPid, wheelevent);

    CFRelease(wheelevent);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate mouse click from Mac App to other Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908620/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-from-mac-app-to-other-application)

Comment: @Willeke This solution may not fit my need, since I cannot the process id other Apps.

Comment: @Willeke I followed your reference but it seems not work, did I make something wrong? I edited the question and posted the code above

Comment: It could be a permission issue. Or try `theEvent.cgEvent` instead of recreating the event.

Comment: Hello, @Willeke. It did ask for permission when the App ran the new code for the first time, and I have enabled it in system configuration. Code has changed to `CGEventPostToPid(AppPid, theEvent.CGEvent);`