# macOS Programming: unable to post mouse events to windows outside the application

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on a toy Swift implementation of Teamviewer where users can collaborate. To achieve this, I'm creating a secondary, remotely controlled cursor on macOS using Cocoa. My goal is to allow this secondary cursor to manipulate windows and post mouse events below it. I've managed to create the cursor and successfully made it move and animate within the window.

However, I'm struggling with enabling mouse events to be fired by this secondary cursor. When I try to post synthetic mouse events, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
    func click(at point: CGPoint) {
        guard let mouseDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left),
              let mouseUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left) else {
            return
        }
        // Post the events to the session event tap
        mouseDown.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
        mouseUp.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
    }
```

I visited the following StackOverflow answer but did not get any useful information out of it to help fix the issue. Enabled Accessibility features, tried posting to specific PIDs, tried posting events twice in a row, all to no avail.
[How to simulate mouse click from Mac App to other Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908620/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-from-mac-app-to-other-application)

Here's the full file if you'd like more context:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  RemoteCursorDemo
//
//  Author: 39050e4eb355e94647722e0580c630798ef4829d on 20/05/23.
//
import Cocoa
import Foundation

class CursorView: NSView {
    let image: NSImage

    init(image: NSImage) {
        self.image = image
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        image.draw(in: dirtyRect)
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var userCursorView: CursorView?
    var remoteCursorView: CursorView?
    var timer: Timer?

    var destination: CGPoint = .zero
    var t: CGFloat = 0
    let duration: TimeInterval = 2 // Duration for remote cursor to move between two points
    let clickProbability: CGFloat = 0.01 // Probability for the remote cursor to click
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let screenRect = NSScreen.main!.frame
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: screenRect,
                          styleMask: .borderless,
                          backing: .buffered,
                          defer: false)
        window.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow)))
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        window.ignoresMouseEvents = true

        let maxHeight: CGFloat = 70.0 // Set your maximum height value here
        if let userImage = NSImage(named: "userCursorImage") {
            let aspectRatio = userImage.size.width / userImage.size.height
            let newWidth = aspectRatio * maxHeight
            userCursorView = CursorView(image: userImage)
            userCursorView!.frame.size = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: maxHeight)
            window.contentView?.addSubview(userCursorView!)
        }

        if let remoteImage = NSImage(named: "remoteCursorImage") {
            let aspectRatio = remoteImage.size.width / remoteImage.size.height
            let newWidth = aspectRatio * maxHeight
            remoteCursorView = CursorView(image: remoteImage)
            remoteCursorView!.frame.size = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: maxHeight)
            window.contentView?.addSubview(remoteCursorView!)
            // Initialize remote cursor position and destination
            remoteCursorView!.frame.origin = randomPointWithinScreen()
            destination = randomPointWithinScreen()
        }

        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.orderFrontRegardless()

        // Hide the system cursor
        NSCursor.hide()

        // Update cursor position every time the mouse is moved or dragged
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved, .leftMouseDragged, .rightMouseDragged]) { [weak self] event in
            self?.updateCursorPosition(with: event)
        }

        // Move the remote cursor every 0.01 second
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.moveRemoteCursor()
        }
        
        // Exit the app when pressing the escape key
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { event in
            if event.keyCode == 53 {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateCursorPosition(with event: NSEvent) {
        var newLocation = event.locationInWindow
        newLocation.y -= userCursorView!.frame.size.height
        userCursorView?.frame.origin = newLocation
    }

    func moveRemoteCursor() {
        if remoteCursorView!.frame.origin.distance(to: destination) < 1 || t >= 1 {
            destination = randomPointWithinScreen()
            t = 0
            let windowPoint = remoteCursorView!.frame.origin
            let screenPoint = window.convertToScreen(NSRect(origin: windowPoint, size: .zero)).origin
            let screenHeight = NSScreen.main?.frame.height ?? 0
            let cgScreenPoint = CGPoint(x: screenPoint.x, y: screenHeight - screenPoint.y)
            click(at: cgScreenPoint)
        } else {
            let newPosition = cubicBezier(t: t, start: remoteCursorView!.frame.origin, end: destination)
            remoteCursorView?.frame.origin = newPosition
            t += CGFloat(0.01 / duration)
        }
    }

    func click(at point: CGPoint) {
        guard let mouseDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left),
              let mouseUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left) else {
            return
        }
        // Post the events to the session event tap
        mouseDown.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
        mouseUp.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
    }


    func drawClickIndicator() {
        let remoteCursorPosition = remoteCursorView!.frame.origin
        let box = NSBox(frame: NSRect(x: remoteCursorPosition.x, y: remoteCursorPosition.y, width: 10, height: 10))
        box.boxType = .custom
        box.borderType = .noBorder
        box.fillColor = NSColor.red
        box.cornerRadius = 5
        box.needsDisplay = true
        window.contentView?.addSubview(box)

        // Fade out the box after a short delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
                context.duration = 0.5
                box.animator().alphaValue = 0
            }, completionHandler: {
                box.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }

    // This function simulates a keyboard event with the specified key code
    func keyboardEvent(with keycode: CGKeyCode) {
        let keyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keycode, keyDown: true)
        let keyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keycode, keyDown: false)
        keyDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        keyUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    }

    
    func randomPointWithinScreen() -> CGPoint {
        guard let screen = NSScreen.main else { return .zero }
        let randomX = CGFloat.random(in: 0...screen.frame.width / 2)
        let randomY = CGFloat.random(in: 100...screen.frame.height)
        return CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
    }

    func cubicBezier(t: CGFloat, start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let control1 = CGPoint(x: 2 * start.x / 3 + end.x / 3, y: start.y)
        let control2 = CGPoint(x: start.x / 3 + 2 * end.x / 3, y: end.y)
        let x = pow(1 - t, 3) * start.x + 3 * pow(1 - t, 2) * t * control1.x + 3 * (1 - t) * pow(t, 2) * control2.x + pow(t, 3) * end.x
        let y = pow(1 - t, 3) * start.y + 3 * pow(1 - t, 2) * t * control1.y + 3 * (1 - t) * pow(t, 2) * control2.y + pow(t, 3) * end.y
                return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Show the system cursor when the application is about to terminate
        NSCursor.unhide()
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return hypot(point.x - x, point.y - y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a small delay between mouseDown and mouseUp like in the linked answer? If I click too fast then my Mac thinks it's by accident and ignores the click.

Comment: i tried adding `usleep(1000)` between the two, no effect. what i'm trying to achieve is possible, right? it's been 2 days, and i can't seem to find the issue. any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried your code and it's clicking everywhere.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Are the clicks affecting the windows below, clicking a button for example? Can you share your xcode, os specs, or any configurations you made. I am not able to reproduce this behavior. Mouse events are not being propagated to the windows below the application.

Comment: I created an Xcode project (macOS app) and replaced the AppDelegate code by the code in the question. At first run I got "MyApp would like to control this computer". After granting access and restarting the app, it works. Maybe it works if you remove the app from system prefs, do a clean build and grant access again.

Comment: It works if I set up a new project and copy the code _every time_. This is not an environment issue with my first project, clearly. I tried cleaning the build as well, but it does not work. I just have to create a new project.

Comment: Also, I realized that the remoteCursor instead of working in parallel with the system cursor, just controls the system cursor. is that expected behavior? i'd imagined synthetic mouse events would allow something like a multicursor environment.